# How to access one element from a multiple array in an array?

Tags: javascript

How would you access the Ford Fiesta in this array, using the `console.log()` method?

```
var vehicles = ["Ford", ["Fiesta", "Taurus", "Explorer"], "Honda", ["Pilot", "Civic", "Accord"], "Toyota", ["Corolla", "Camry", "Prius"]];
```

I tried using `console.log(vehicles[0][1])`

Comment: Which would have given you `'o'`, which should have been a clue to the problem. An array of strings-or-arrays probably isn't the best data structure here.

Answer (score 1):

You can't achieve what you want in an easy way, because the data structure is faulty to begin with. If you have a good foundation, the rest of the pieces will fall into place on their own.

Here is a data structure as an object:

```
var vehicles = {
  "Ford": ["Fiesta", "Taurus", "Explorer"],
  "Honda": ["Pilot", "Civic", "Accord"],
  "Toyota": ["Corolla", "Camry", "Prius"]
};

console.log(vehicles['Ford'][0]) // 'Fiesta'
```

Here is a data structure as an array:

```
var vehicles = [
  {brand: "Ford",   model: ["Fiesta", "Taurus", "Explorer"]},
  {brand: "Honda",  model: ["Pilot", "Civic", "Accord"]},
  {brand: "Toyota", model: ["Corolla", "Camry", "Prius"]},
];

console.log(vehicles[0][0]) // 'Fiesta'
```

You didn't describe how you wanted to use this, otherwise I would had given you some methods for searching inside these data structures.

Answer (score 0):

The array structure you are using is rather unconventional but the following function will work:

```js
const vehicles = ["Ford", ["Fiesta", "Taurus", "Explorer"], "Honda", ["Pilot", "Civic", "Accord"], "Toyota", ["Corolla", "Camry", "Prius"]];

function carModel(arr,make,model){
  return [arr[make*2],arr[make*2+1][model]];
}

console.log(carModel(vehicles,0,1)); // Ford Taurus
console.log(carModel(vehicles,2,2)); // Toyota Prius
```

Answer (score -1):

you can access the same way you access a 2d array. But there is a difference here that some your elements are not exactly an array soo you need to be accurate about your postions. In my opinion you should use a different data structure.